# Did I make a good choice in the tenses

Tags: past-tense

> I  heard some strange noises for  two days after waking up and it  scared me. I am glad that today I have not heard  them

Is that correct?

I have a doubt because heard indicates that the noises are over  in fact I  don't know (present perfect at the end of the second sentence) so would it be better to write  "I have been hearing or have heard , it has been scaring or has scared

Comment: "For the past two days I've been hearing some strange noises after waking up and it's been scaring me. I'm glad I haven't heard them today. If you use past simple the event seems to be something that happened in the past, not recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, completely correct.  Just be sure to end the sentence with a period.

"Scared" is a good choice, as it scared you in the past to a degree.  The reader will infer that you are still scared, though perhaps not quite as much.

"I have not heard them" is a good choice, as it conveys that they might still be there or you might still yet hear them soon, but today you have not heard them.  Maybe the cause of those noises is gone; maybe not.

"I am glad that I have not heard them today" is slightly more colloquial and I would prefer that wording if I were writing a narrative story in the present tense, or certainly in a conversation.

Comment: What do you think of Anouk's answer . She told me it would be better to use present perfect continuous

Comment: Patrick says "it scared you in the past". In my answer the being scared happened in the two days prior to "today".  It's a different perspective, not better.